# Binding issue on properties with get; vs with get; set; in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a XF app. In my ViewModel I have the following:

```
public ICommand ActBtnCmd { get; }
public ICommand AdpBtnCmd { get; }

public SettingsTabViewModel(SettingsTabPage settingsTabPage)
{
   ActBtnCmd = new Command<Templates.Button>((btn) => MessagingCenter.Send(this, "ActBtn", btn));
   AdpBtnCmd = new Command<Templates.Button>((btn) => MessagingCenter.Send(this, "AdpBtn", btn));
}
```

And in my `XAML`:

```
<t:Button Text="{Binding ActBtnText}" 
          TapCommand="{Binding ActBtnCmd}" 
          WidthRequest="30" 
          Theme="{Binding Theme}" />
```

Debugging in iOS is no problem. But when I debug the app in Android I get these messages in Application Output window:

```
Binding: 'ActBtnCmd' property not found on 'xxx.SettingsTabViewModel', target property: 'xxx.Templates.Button.TapCommand'
Binding: 'AdpBtnCmd' property not found on 'xxx.SettingsTabViewModel', target property: 'xxx.Templates.Button.TapCommand'
```

But when I changed my property like below then the messages are gone:

```
public ICommand ActBtnCmd { get; set; }
public ICommand AdpBtnCmd { get; set; }
```

Can anyone explain to me why am I getting these messages? And why am I only getting it in Android?

Comment: What version of Forms are you using?

Comment: Version 3.6.0.220655

Comment: Your code is fine, read-only props should not produce that `Log.Warning` output (and my code on that version of Forms using read-only props does not produce those warnings. Try deleting the app/apk from the device/emulator and do a clean/rebuild :  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/c3a5a6b850bc24ad8ff9801ae7c8b92a6e1be6dc/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindingExpression.cs#L135

Comment: @IvanIčin ???? `public ICommand ActBtnCmd { get; }` That is read-only prop and thus assigned in the .ctor (as shown in the code posted...) And the "Binding:" warning is not a compiler-based warning, it is a runtime application output in the expression binding and should not happen based upon the code I linked to (the only way that prop would|should produce that output is if it was flagged as `OneWayToSource`.

Comment: @SushiHangover OK, missed that in C# 6

Comment: @SushiHangover did this and still getting the same messages

Comment: How and when do you set DataContext? Maybe the timing is platform-dependend in your case

Comment: MVVM side note : the fact that, apparently, your view model has a reference to its corresponding view is already not a good sign of things to come.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that this has to do with the *Binding Mode* of the bindable property being bind to.

The default binding mode for most properties is `OneWay`. When these properties are data-binding targets, then the target property is set from the source. Which only needs a `get;` from the property.

If how ever the binding mode is `TwoWay` then the source property will need both a `get;` and `set;`. This means that when the a property is a data-binding target, then the target is set from the source (as usual) but the source is also set from the target.

But if the source property is readonly (as in `get;` only) then you may see that message as the binder is unable to ensure that it can write back to the source.

To test this theory I would suggest [Overriding the Binding Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#overriding-the-binding-mode)

> If the default binding mode on the target property is not suitable for a particular data binding, it's possible to override it by setting the `Mode` property of `Binding` (or the `Mode` property of the `Binding` markup extension) to one of the members of the `BindingMode` enumeration.

```
<t:Button Text="{Binding ActBtnText}" 
    TapCommand="{Binding ActBtnCmd Mode=OneWay}" <!-- Note the Mode used -->
    WidthRequest="30" 
    Theme="{Binding Theme}" />
```

By setting the `Mode` to `OneWay` it should let the parser know not to expect a `set;` on the property and remove the warning.

As for why the run-time experience is different on the platforms, it could be that different XAML parsers are used for the platforms, where one uses a different default binding mode or ignores that warning message.

Reference [Xamarin.Forms Binding Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Get; can only be set using the constructor. Change it to :

```
{ get; private set; }
```

This way only the get is publicly available, but still modifiable by the class's methods.